# Connecting Javacode to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

I have a .jsp file and a .java file.
I tried using annotations but the two files don't seem to connect.

This is the Java code

```
@WebServlet("/WEB-INF/JSP/restaurant.htm")
public class restaurant extends HttpServlet{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final String VIEW = "/WEB-INF/JSP/restaurant.jsp";
private RestaurantService restaurantService = new RestaurantService();


protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Restaurant> restaurants = restaurantService.findAll();
    request.setAttribute("restaurants", restaurants);

    request.getRequestDispatcher(VIEW).forward(request, response);
}
```

And this is my JSP code

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt"%>
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}" />
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Selecteer uw restaurant</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Selecteer uw restaurant</h1>

<c:forEach var="restaurant" items="${restaurants}">
    <c:url value="/gerechten" var="restaurantURL">
        <c:param name="rest">${restuarant.restaurantId}</c:param>
    </c:url>
    <a href="restaurantURL"> <img alt="${restaurant.naam}"
        src="${restaurant.image}"> <br /> ${restaurant.naam}
    </a><br/><br/>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

It's only a few lines but even this won't work..
Do I use a web.xml an if so, how do I use it?

thanks in advance!

Comment: The string value you give the `@WebServlet` is the url pattern that the servlet will handle.

Comment: (**1**) You can shorten your `URL Pattern` to something like `"/restaurant.htm"` (**2**) Make sure that you use `html` vs `htm` consistently.

Answer (score 0):

With Servlet 3.0, you no longer need a web descriptor (except for some configurations). With the [`@WebServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation you are basically replacing the `<servlet>` and `<servlet-mapping>` elements.

The default attribute of the `@WebServlet` annotation is the `value` attribute which holds

> The URL patterns of the servlet

Right now, your url pattern is `/WEB-INF/JSP/restaurant.htm`. So you could access your application at (assuming localhost, port 8080)

```
http://localhost:8080/context/WEB-INF/JSP/restaurant.htm
                             ^ start of your url pattern
```

I assume this is not what you want. So modify the `@WebServlet` `value` attribute to use the url you want to use to access your servlet.